# Aplicar funciones definidas a un dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo la siguiente función para sacar un número específico que he llamado **"k**":

```
def sacar_k(m, delta_x):
return (m*g)/delta_x #la g es una constante
```

Y quiero crear una columna nueva en este dataframe con ese número **"k"**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un poco claro, pero no está demás aclarar que quiero que la columna **"Masa"** actúe como la variable **"m"** de la  función y la columna **"∆x"** como la variable **"delta_x"** de la función definida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no es necesario que crees una función para una operación tan sencilla, en el ejemplo en cuestión es posible aplicar la aritmética a las listas que puedes obtener del dataframe de pandas

asumiendo que tu dataframe es df

```
df['k'] = df['Masa'].values * g / df['∆x'].values # El .values obtiene los valores en un array
```

o si aún quieres usar tu función

```
df['k'] = sacar_k(df['Masa'].values,df['∆x'].values)
```

Comment: Gracias!, es exactamente lo que quería.

Comment: Con gusto, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta, te recomiendo que accedas a la documentación de pandas si sabes un poco de inglés, es bastante clara y directa https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/